# Install a game from a Zip File

Tags: games

How do you install a game from a zip file? I downloaded gems from the Ubuntu software centre and they offered a free download it came as a zip file how do you install it?

Comment: You can use gunzip for example

Comment: Another program to install, I just want to install the game?

Comment: Gary, did you try to unzip the file and look for the instructions inside?

Comment: @GaryWheadon - add it as an answer then :D

Answer (score 0):

use `zip`, `gunzip` or a `tar` command to unzip the file first.

To install:

If the file extension is `.deb` or  `.Use`:

```
sudo dpkg -i file name
```

If it is a bash scrip, then use this command:

```
bash  filename
```

If it is in python, then use:

```
python3 filename.py
```